# .net linq with regex ismatch in where

Tags: c#, regex, linq

In the following C# method, I know that the Directory.GetFileNsmes() does return the list of files. And, I can add in the Where contains(contact) which works. However for the life of me I can not determine why the searchPatter.IsMatch() fails to find files. I've tested the pattern in http://regexpal.com/ and it qorks as expected. The namePattern is "^\d{3}(.*).pdf" and there should be a match.

```
 public static List<string> GetFileNames(string pathName, string namePattern, string contact)
 {
   var searchPattern = new Regex(namePattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   var files = Directory.GetFiles(pathName).Where(f => searchPattern.IsMatch(f));
       //.Where(f => f.Contains(contact));
   return files.ToList();
 }
```

If this is already answered somewhere please let me know but I've not been able to locate it. I thought this it was pretty simple and straight forward.

Answer (score 5):

`Directory.GetFiles` will return fill file path which will be `Drive\Directory\File.ext`. That's why your pattern doesn't seem to match. You need `FileName` alone as subject. Try this

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(pathName)
                 .Where(f => searchPattern.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(f)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Directory.GetFiles() returns a list of filenames appended to the path supplied as a parameter. Your regular expression is "^\d{3}(.*).pdf", that is a string beginning with three digits. If you supplied a string that's  an absolute path, it will start with either "/" on Unix or "C:\" on Windows and if it's a relative path, it will start with a directory name. Your code would work if pathName was just an empty string and you were searching the current directory.